# Why an empty List of first-order theories is consistent?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Given an empty list of first order theories :$ T=Ø$

Why can it be considered as consistent?

(in the workbook, the answer is because every structure can represnted by it, but

I didnt really understand how a structure can repersented by an an empty list)

Comment: "If I said nothing, then I'm not wrong".

Comment: What book are you using? (A structure isn't represented by a theory; rather, a structure may or may not *satisfy* a theory. Smaller theories say less, and are hence easier to satisfy. The empty theory says nothing, and every structure trivially satisfies it.)

Comment: I'm from cyprus, hence there might be a missconception because of language barrier.

Comment: So if I have an order list which contains all possible statemnts, is it safe to assume that it is not consistent?

Comment: @user6394019 It's definitely not consistent; whenever a statement and its negation both appear in a theory, the theory is definitely inconsistent. (Note that the converse doesn't hold; a theory can be "not obviously inconsistent" but still inconsistent.) That said, I'm a bit confused by the talk of *lists*; a theory is just a *set* of sentences, and the order doesn't matter.